# Getting Due tasks in coming 5 days using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to get items whom date is either today or is in coming 7 days, I might be trying to do it totally wrong but this is what I am trying so far,

```
 var CountDueTasks = 0;
 var CountDueFiveTasks = 0;
 var CountOverdueTasks = 0;

 $.each(data.GetTasksResult.Tasks, function (index, item) {

 // count overdue tasks                   
 if (Date.now() >= Date.parse(item.duedate)) {    // duedate format = 17 December 2014 18:00
            CountOverdueTasks = CountOverdueTasks + 1;
 }
```

**Problems**

- I am not sure how to count tasks that are due today (because duedate is always 18:00)
- I am not sure how to count tasks that are due in next 5 days :(

Comment: How are your dates coming out? date time formatted or unix style timestamps?

Comment: Dates are coming out as Miliseconds

Comment: Ah :( it may be a little beyond me

Comment: No answers so far, I am going to look into date.js

Comment: Unfortunately I am better with PHP and could have told you in PHP - however UNIX is easier to deal with